# How to get one number from PhoneNumberChooserTask

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, phone-number

Is there any simply way to get one contact (name and number) from PhoneNumberChooserTask and save it to String without using method .show()?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you will specify name and get it in your app without showing the selection menu - this is not possible.

Comment: Search number by name - I did not mean it. I give a simply example. When I choose number '1', method returns me the telephone number of the first person on the selection menu. Meybe it is possible?

Comment: In other words, you want to get all contacts from contacts book without users allowance?

Comment: yes, exactly. I need to perform a method which can call to the person from selection menu without showing this list with contacts. Of course, I want to have information about this person, for example - I click the button and I phone to first person from contact list, and in the field TextBlock I see name of first person from constact list. Thanks for interest in the topic